# segmantation fault malloc pointers functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, coredump

hello guys this is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int power(int a, int b) {
    int exponent = b, result = 1;
    while (exponent != 0) {
        result = result * a;
        exponent--;
    }
    //printf("%d",result);
    return result;
}

int fill_it(char ** p, int N, int fliptimes, int column2) {
    if (N < 0) return 0;
    int counter = 0, l;
    char a = 'H';
    for (l = 0; l < power(2, fliptimes); l++) {
        p[l][column2] = a;
        counter++;
        if (counter == (power(2, N) / 2)) {
            counter = 0;
            if (a == 'H') a = 'T';
            if (a == 'T') a = 'H';
        }
    }
    fill_it(p, N--, fliptimes, column2++);
}

int main() {
    int i, fores, j, l, m;
    char ** p;
    printf("how many times did you toss the coin?:");
    scanf("%d", & fores);
    p = (char ** ) malloc((power(2, fores)) * sizeof(char * ));
    for (i = 0; i < fores; i++)
        p[i] = (char * ) malloc(fores * sizeof(char));
    fill_it(p, fores, fores, 0);
    for (l = 0; l < power(2, fores); l++) {
        for (m = 0; m < fores; m++) {
            printf("%c", p[l][m]);
        }
    }
    printf(",");
}
```

it does compile.But when i run the program it returns a "segmantation fault (core dumped)" error

i know it means that i tried to access memory,i dont have acces to but i dont understand which part of the program is defective

Comment: Read up on how to format your question. The code here is quite unreadable.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: (Unrelated to the seggie, but `if (a == 'H') a = 'T'; if (a == 'T') a = 'H';` will make `a == 'H'` in both cases. You need an `else` here.)

Comment: Run your code in a debugger (ie gdb) and it will tell you where in your code it is crashing

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the input you gave, as well as the output you got ? Can you also indicate where the segmentation fault happened ?

Comment: You want to call `fill_it` recursively and control it with `N`, but here: `fill_it(p, N--, ...)`, you don't call with an decreased `N`, but with the old value of `N`, which is only decreased after returning. De facto, you never terminate your recursion. Use `N - 1` here.

Comment: Valgrind is your friend when you have to find memory error, you should try it

Comment: Calculate the size and verify it, before calling malloc.

Comment: (You call ´fill_it` recursively, but you have got a tail recursion here, which you can turn into a loop. With two nested loops, the function would be much clearer, in my opinion.)

Comment: @MOehm there's also a similar problem with `column2++` in the recursive call

Comment: what can i do to make it more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're not allocating enough memory. This line is fine

```
p = (char ** ) malloc((power(2, fores)) * sizeof(char * ));
```

but this loop is only allocating memory for part of the 2-dimensional array.

```
for (i = 0; i < fores; i++)
    p[i] = (char * ) malloc(fores * sizeof(char));
```

The memory allocation should look more like this...

```
foresSquared = power(2, fores);
p = malloc(foresSquared*sizeof(char *));
for (i = 0; i < foresSquared; i++)
    p[i] = malloc(fores);
```

Since the result of `power` is going to be consistent, it makes sense to store the value in a variable and use that rather than recalculating it. It'll make the code clearer too.

You also don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` as C handles that for you. And `sizeof(char)` isn't needed as it's guaranteed to always be 1.

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer can't see where in my fixed version of the code that I'm doing?

Comment: Oh, whoops, my bad, I misread. It was on the first code section. I'm really terrbile at understanding written stuff...

Comment: @ChrisTurner thank you very much,you made my day! :-)

Comment: @dimitraaaa if my answer is right it's traditional to mark it as such with a tick